# Como resolver o erro InvalidCharacterError

Tags: jquery, syntax-error

Estou utilizando uma requisição `ajax`, que me retorna um json, de uma página `.php`, com o nome de uma cidade do **Mato grosso do sul** chamada: **Antônio João**.

O erro é de javascript. Que diz o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Que código está gerando esse erro? Interessa o que tem na linha 1202 e em torno dela.

Comment: @bfavaretto, você é o melhor *.* SOMENTE essa simples observação me ajudou a identificar o erro. vlw!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algumas funções em javascript não permitem espaços vazios entre caracteres. Um exemplo, no meu caso, foi o `add()`. Estou utilizando para adicionar uma classList

```
var nomediv = 'Antônio João';
element.classList.add(nomediv);
```

### Como resolver?

O element.classList  retorna um `DOMTokenList` dos atributos de classe do elemento. element é um DOMTokenList que representa o atributo de classe do elementNodeReference. Portanto, sabe-se que por regra, `não é permitido espaços para compor o nome de uma classe`. E para resolver o erro foi implementando um simples **REGEX**:

```
var nomediv = 'Antônio João';
element.classList.add(nomediv.value.replace(/\s/g, '') );
```

[FONTE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: Usar acento em nome de classe também é pedir pra ter problema. Por que não usa o ID do banco de dados, em vez do nome da cidade? E por que não colocar isso como id do elemento em vez de classe ?

Comment: São soluções alternativas e não soluções assertivas para este problema, @bfavaretto.

Comment: No mínimo remover os acentos seria uma alternativa acertada...